# What is the correct URI design for a REST service with associated resources

Tags: web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

Hi all,

I'm new to REST and Web API. I'm a bit confused on how to design URIs for my resources.

Given that I have a domain with the following resources: Blogs, Posts and Users.

```
Blog (1) ------ (0..*) Post (0..*) ------ (1) User
```

A blog can have many posts and each post is associated with one blog. An user can have many posts and each post is associated with one user.

For Blog and User resources the URIs would be like the following:

```
GET /blogs - get list of all blogs
GET /blogs/{id} - get blog by id
POST /blogs - create new blog
PUT /blogs/{id} - update blog
DELETE /blogs/{id} - delete blog

GET /users- get list of all users
GET /users/{id} - get user by id
POST /users - create new user
PUT /users/{id} - update user
DELETE /users/{id} - delete user
```

But what about Posts resource? How to handle associations? I'm thinking of the following alternatives - which ones are correct and why?

-- Get all posts by blog

```
1. GET /blogs/{id}/posts
or
2. GET /posts?blogid={id}
```

-- Create new post in a blog

```
3. POST /blogs/{id}/posts
or
4. POST /posts (here I would then in the payload send the IDs of the resources this post is associated with. BlogId and UserId)
```

-- Get all posts by blog and by user

```
5. GET /blogs/{id}/posts?userid={id}
or
6. GET /posts?blogid={id}&amp;userid={id}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction here, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Since a post is always associated with a blog and a user ID, I would choose options 1, 3 and 5:

```
GET /blogs/{id}/posts
POST /blogs/{id}/posts
GET /blogs/{id}/posts?userid={id}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first question you should ask yourself is how important it is to you that your API is truly RESTful? It's actually a lot more fiddly than it seems to achieve this.

1. Is your API going to be consumed only by your own software\organisation?
2. Will your API be accompanied by documentation?

If the answer to 1 or 2 above is true, then the value of being truly RESTful is questionable... it's all or nothing with REST so either you go the whole hog or you don't worry.

For an API to be a true REST API, it must be discoverable from a single entry point (see here: http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven). Each call should return information on other related calls that can be made on that resource.. usually via links of some kind, this is one possible structure:

```
{
    "Id" : 1,
    "Identifier" : "123's First Blog",
    "links" : [
        {
            "rel": "http://myapi/res/posts",
            "href": "http://myapi/blog/1/posts"
        },
        {
            "rel": "http://myapi/res/users",
            "href": "http://myapi/user/123"
        }
    ]
}
```

The rel is a link to a summary\definition of the resource, and the href should point to the api itself.

Anyways, the point of all this is that if you do want to be truly RESTful, then let the links between resources and uris dictate the design. Think about how you would discover the particulars for each call from a single starting point, and the structure should reveal itself much like software design through TDD.

If you don't need to be RESTful, then things become much simpler. Just design your API in the most natural way for you, your architecture, and your developers. If you document things properly, then this will lead to a much more efficient API and one that is quicker to develop against.

Mario's answer to this question is sound, and I would also favour those options over the others. I just thought you should know the whole story that accompanies such a desicion.

If this doesn't make sense or you would like more information then post a comment and I'll try to help :)

Comment: If you want some further reading on the merits and particulars of REST in APIs, take a look here also http://roysvork.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/why-im-giving-rest-a-rest/